# Web scraping data from an interactive chart that changes with cursor position on the screen

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to web scrape data from this url, http://poker.srv.ualberta.ca/preflop. On the page you see an interactive table who only shows the preflop actions if you move your cursor over the different squares. I checked the source code and all the info is in the class stat summary, but stat summary changes with cursor position. Is there a way to use lxml and requests to extrapolate the ENTIRE table? I am able to do it for a single position but not all.

My code so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get("http://poker.srv.ualberta.ca/preflop")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that there is no AJAX call to load that data behind graphs.

Only way they can load that graph's data is from those JS files on their site.

I suggest your to look over all the JS files and see how they are computing that values.

Here are some of the JS files on their servers.

http://poker.srv.ualberta.ca/data/crPreflop.js

and

http://poker.srv.ualberta.ca/data/cPreflop.js

You will have to spend a day studying data inside those files and you will figure out.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this using just lxml and requests. It is a d3 chart that you can probably scrape using a headless browser like phantomjs (to emulate the mouse mouvements). The data you are trying to get, though is available as javascript objects  if you check the page source ( before the end ob body tag ). here is an example of the files I found . http://poker.srv.ualberta.ca/data/rPreflop.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Selenium" to simulate the click and hold action while you can get and parse the text you want to scrape. But this way is a bit slow.

A better way is to look into the website structure and track where the source file is (often times a csv file) and simply scrape that file and parse it. This is much more efficient but requires some time.